# Conditional Aggregation within Dynamic Pivot Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables say:

```
Orders:
id | Name | Amount | Date
1  | ABC  | 100    | 2020-10-01
2  | XYZ  | 200    | 2020-10-01
3  | MNO  | 250    | 2020-11-01

Order_details:
id | Item | Qty
1  | A    | 2
1  | B    | 1
1  | C    | 3
2  | X    | 1
3  | A    | 4
```

Now I want to fetch the data using the date on which the order was made.

Say if I want to fetch the data of `2020-10-01` the output should be something like this:

```
id | Name | Amount | Date       | Item1 | Qty | Item2 | Qty ...
1  | ABC  | 100    | 2020-10-01 | A     | 2   | B     | 1
2  | XYZ  | 200    | 2020-10-01 | X     | 1
```

I tried to fetch it using a subquery, but I was not sure how to print that data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PIVOT is not implemented in MySQL.

Comment: is Orders Name always  three letters string?

Comment: Why a subquery?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev No, it will contain the name of the person who ordered. Just for an example I wrote a 3 letters string.

Comment: @Strawberry My approach was using a subquery. Any other approach will also work for me.

Comment: In that case, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Conditional Aggregation within Dynamic Pivot Statement which works even for DB version `5.5` :

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709551615;
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @date = '2020-10-01';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           DISTINCT
             CONCAT(
                    'MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ', rn,' THEN Item END ) AS Item', rn,
                    ', MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ', rn,' THEN Qty END ) AS Qty'
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( 
        SELECT *, @rn := IF(@i = id, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn, @i := id
          FROM Order_details
          JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @rn := 0) i
         ORDER BY id, Item
  ) od;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT o.id, o.name, o.amount, o.date,',@sql,
                   ' FROM Orders o
                     JOIN (
                           SELECT *, @rn := IF(@i = id, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn, @i := id
                             FROM Order_details
                             JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @rn := 0) i
                            ORDER BY id, Item    
                          ) od
                       ON od.id = o.id
                    WHERE o.date = "',@date,'"
                    GROUP BY o.id, o.name, o.amount, o.date
                    ORDER BY o.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

where parameter value might be updated within the second line ( `SET @date = '2020-10-01';` ) . Btw, the function `GROUP_CONCAT()` has an upper length limit(*for the parameter `group_concat_max_len` with default value of `1024`*) that might be updated(*upto the max value of `18446744073709551615`*) for the current session for the cases the table has multiple distinct items, so having lots of columns.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=67aa7c765770757432a3f1edf9fb7596)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me in the beginning but now it  shows me some syntax error. I didnt change anything in this query.

```SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Orders o
                     JOIN (
                          ' at line 1
```

Comment: Hi @MdAkramKazmi , you're welcome. Can you show the case where you met an error within in the demo?

Comment: Got the issue, the query does not work when there are more than 11 entries in the order_details table for a particular id.
Have updated it in the demo.

Comment: @MdAkramKazmi then you need to increase the value for the parameter `group_concat_max_len` . Check out the updated answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed maximum number of items per orders, you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select o.*,
    max(case when od.rn = 1 then item end) item1,
    max(case when od.rn = 1 then qty  end) qty1,
    max(case when od.rn = 2 then item end) item2,
    max(case when od.rn = 2 then qty  end) qty2,
    max(case when od.rn = 3 then item end) item3,
    max(case when od.rn = 3 then qty  end) qty3
from orders o
inner join (
    selet od.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by item) rn
    from order_details od
) od on od.id = o.id
group by o.id
```

You can extend the `select` clause with more conditional expressions to handle more than 3 items per order.

Note that window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: The issue here is the number of items can increase to 10 as well. We don't have a limit on the number of items per order.